# Android Gallery display selected image

Tags: android, android-layout

I the following code i am trying to display the image that is selected in the gallery.But i get a default android image and not the image that i saved.What am i doing wrong how to resolve this..

```
package HGallery.com;

import HGallery.com.R;
import HGallery.com.HGalleryActivity.ImageAdapter;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HGalleryActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final ImageView iv=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    iv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);



    Gallery g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
    g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    g.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            //Toast.makeText(HGalleryActivity.this, "here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Toast.makeText(HGalleryActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Drawable d=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
            //Toast.makeText(HGalleryActivity.this, ""+d, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            iv.setImageDrawable(d);     


        }
    });



}
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    int mGalleryItemBackground;
    private Context mContext;

    private Integer[] mImageIds = {
            R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2,
            R.drawable.sample_3

    };

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
        TypedArray a = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.HelloGallery);
        mGalleryItemBackground = a.getResourceId(
                R.styleable.HelloGallery_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
        a.recycle();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mImageIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);

        i.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
        i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 100));
        i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        i.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground);

        return i;
    }

/*  public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }*/
}
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<TextView  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="@string/hello"
/>
  <Gallery xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@+id/gallery"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
<ImageView  android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_width="320px" android:layout_height="250px"></ImageView>
<!-- <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageView2" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/icon"></ImageView>-->
```

Comment: Not sure if this is related, but your onItemClick method does not refer to the specific item clicked. It only refers to some single image in the drawable folder, whatever the image called "icon" is.

Comment: icon is the one which is availble by default right.Let me  put the question this way onclcik how can i populate the image view with the image selected currently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method inside your ImageAdapter called `public Object getItem(int position)` should be modified to return the appropriate `mImageIds[]` by using the `position` argument. Then, inside `onItemClick`, you can call `parent.getItemAtPosition(position)` to get the resource id.

If you want to use that method for things other than the ids, you can write your own get method (which I'd call getResourceId), and call `((ImageAdapter)parent.getAdapter()).getResourceId(position))`.

Comment: Hi could you show me the code for the first implementation that you have said.

Comment: It's very simple. Just replace `return position;` with `return mImageIds[position];` and change the return type (because it's not part of the method signature, although you could leave it as Object, and just cast the result). In `onItemClick`, you'd change the line to `Drawable d=getResources().getDrawable(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));`