# How to get the image id of an image in the Android gallery?

Tags: android, image, android-gallery

Here is what I am trying to do in one of my activities:

1. Open up the Android Gallery. (Done)
2. When clicking on one of the images in the gallery I want to

   - Get the ID of that image (????)
   - Save the Image to the SharedPreferences (Already know how to do that)
   - Display the image in an ImageView (Already know how to do that)

So how do I get the ID from an image in the gallery?

P.S.: Is that approach of displaying an image ok like that?

Comment: What is the Term ID as per your knowledge ? or Accept any answer from below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here are some examples of how to pick an image in the gallery:

1. [How To Pick Image From Gallery](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2012/05/pick-image-from-galary-android-app.html)
2. [Android Gallery display selected image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674896/android-gallery-display-selected-image)

hope that you'll get idea from these links.